# Style not working on this table

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I have neglected this for awhile now just to focus on the working part. But now am more concerned about this part and it's not going away

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:none">
    <tr>
            <td class="editor-label" width="140px">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
            </td>
            <td class="editor-field">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
            </td>
    </tr>
    ....

</table>
```

As you can see I put removed cellpadding, cellspacing, added border=none and none of this fixed it. Why is this table no responding to css?

The rows lines are not going away. I want to remove the lines.

I have also remove all class attributes on the `td` but this didn't still work

### UPDATE

I removed this in the Style.css and it worked. **But why couldn't I use inline style to override the style sheet settings?**

```
table td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #e8eef4;
}
```

For now I will just have my own style. Why was the assumption that every table must have lines?

Comment: In your `<table>`, it should be `cellspacing`. It seems you typoed. :)

Comment: Is your `css` loaded via `link` ?

Comment: We'll need to see the generated HTML and/or CSS to know for sure what's going on. A computed result is only a little helpful.

Comment: I have seen the issue, it's in the style.css file

Comment: Try `<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border='0'>` and remove all classes from the `td`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something in your CSS is setting the `border` attribute on your `td`s or the `border-collapse` attribute on `table`. Without a paste of your CSS and HTML somewhere, it's difficult to say for sure where the problem is.

If you'd rather dodge the CSS file, you can set CSS inline. Try some of these:

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse !important; border-spacing: 0 !important;">
```

or

```
<td style="border: 0 !important;">
```

The `!important` keyword will over-ride anything set in an external stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

it would be

```
style="border:none;"
```

if anything - with the semi-colon.

To remove the borders

```
table{
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Semi-colon doesn't require if there is only one style.

Comment: @sporkbox, Yes it's but not a problem in this case.